# Code blocks on aspx page

Tags: web-config

I couldn't use javascript on my page, have "Code blocks are not allowed in this file".
I added

```
<PageParserPaths>    
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true" />    
</PageParserPaths>
```

into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config on my Server, by nothing changed.
Help plz, what's the problem?

Comment: where is the page located? Master Page gallery?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use `<script/>` blocks with the `runat` attribute set to `true` - which means that the script should be executed on the server side, or are you trying to just do client side JavaScripts?

If it is the first one, I strongly discourages you to do it this way. Allowing code blocks like this and modifying the web.config file to allow it is opening your farm up for all kinds of vulnerabilities and performance degradation. There is a reason for this being prohibited by default.
If you really need code running in the pages, make a real codebehind solution. That is create a class deriving from Page (or any of the SharePoint derivatives).

If it's the latter case, remove the `runat="true"` attribute on your `script` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Master Page Gallery, please use

> VirtualPath="/_mpg/*"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code if your Page layouts are located in the Master Page Gallery.

```
 <PageParserPaths>
        <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/_catalogs/masterpage/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
 </PageParserPaths>
```

Comment: No, I try to use Code at custom aspx page, not at master page.

Comment: it will work if your page layouts are existing in Master page gallery

Comment: or is your page layout located in Layouts folder?